Azure Subscriber Function not running with Managed Identity
I have an Azure Subscriber Function listening to a Service Bus topic. It is working perfectly under Service Bus connectionString settings. However, I want to convert this to run under Managed Identity. I have already checked few links like this and this with few other topics from Microsoft Learn but couldn't help.
What I have done:
Under Service Bus IAM, assigned Azure Service Bus Data Receiver and Azure Service Bus Data Sender roles to the previously deployed Subscriber Function (that was running under connectionString). Also added a Data Owner role to myself for testing purposes (which I don't need actually):

code is like this: where \new indicates new lines that I have added to my existing code.
public class Subscriber1


{
   private readonly ILogger<Subscriber1> _logger;

   public Subscriber1(ILogger<Subscriber1> logger)
   {
     _logger = logger;
   }

   [Function(nameof(Subscriber1))]
   public async Task Run(
           [ServiceBusTrigger("topic", "Subscriber1", Connection = "SBConnectionString")]
           ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
           ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
   {
     var userAssignedClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("User_Assigned_Client_Id"); //new
     var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(
                     new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
                     {
                       ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId
                     });                                                                        //new
     var fullyQualifiedNamespace = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SBConnectionString__fullyQualifiedNamespace");   //new
     var client = new ServiceBusClient(fullyQualifiedNamespace, credential);                                            //new
     var processor = client.CreateProcessor("topic", new ServiceBusProcessorOptions());                                 //new

 _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
 _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
 _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);

 // Complete the message
 await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);


 }
 }

local.settings.json file
    {
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "SBConnectionString": "", /* I have left that blank, what should I enter here? */
    "SBConnectionString__fullyQualifiedNamespace": "domainname.servicebus.windows.net",
    "User_Assigned_Client_Id": "object id of the subcriber function"

  }
}

So what should I do to make it work a) locally and b) after deployment?

Add Azure_Tenant_ID app setting in local.settings.json:
local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "SBConnectionString__fullyQualifiedNamespace": "<Servicebus_namespace>.servicebus.windows.net",
    "User_Assigned_Client_Id": "<CLient_ID>",
    "AZURE_TENANT_ID": "<Tenant_ID>"
  }
}


I have used your code and able to run the service bus function using User assigned managed identity.

[Function(nameof(Function1))]
public async Task Run(
   [ServiceBusTrigger("topic1", "subscriber1", Connection = "SBConnectionString")]
   ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
   ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
{
    var userAssignedClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("User_Assigned_Client_Id"); 
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(
                    new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
                    {
                        ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId
                    });                                                                     
    var fullyQualifiedNamespace = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SBConnectionString__fullyQualifiedNamespace");  
    var client = new ServiceBusClient(fullyQualifiedNamespace, credential);                                           
    var processor = client.CreateProcessor("topic", new ServiceBusProcessorOptions());                               

    _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
    _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
    _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);
    await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
}

Local response :


Deploy the function to Azure function App.
Add the application settings under Function App=>Environment Variables:

 "ServiceBusConnection__fullyQualifiedNamespace": "<Servicebus_Namespace>.servicebus.windows.net",
 "User_Assigned_Client_Id": "<Client_ID>",



Enable User Assigned Managed Identity in Azure function app.
Assign Azure Service Bus Data Owner role to User Assigned Managed Identity.

Portal:

Able to trigger the function app using managed identity:




Thanks, I was able to resolve it this morning, and now looked at your answer as well. Happy to mark it as acceptable, appreciate it if you can you answer these questions:

I believe this User Assigned Client Id is the object ID of the user right?
What if after deployment I only assign the Data Sender/Receiver role to the System Assigned Identity (i.e. to my function), do I need any settings in AppSettings in addition to ServiceBusConnection_fullyQualifiedNamespace?


I believe this User Assigned Client Id is the object ID of the user right > It is the client id of user assigned managed identity, refer Image. do I need any settings in AppSettings in addition to ServiceBusConnection_fullyQualifiedNamespace > ServiceBusConnection_fullyQualifiedNamespace setting is enough.

i have just moved it to another environment but annoyed to see that its not triggering at all. i have assigned appropriate roles and set up sbconnstring__fullyqualifiednamespace in AppSettings but its not triggering at all. do i need to add client id in AppSettings  of Azure Function after deploying or was it only to run it locally?

Are you using System Assigned Identity?

for running it locally , i assigned service bus owner role to myself. but after deployment, i use system assigned identity and assign data sender and data receiver roles to the function itself.

Did you add User assigned managed identity in function app?

If yes, you should not enable system assigned identity and yes, you have to add client id in the application settings of function app.

yes, just edited my answer above

thanks I'll try it tomorrow morning and get back to you. Thanks for being a wonderful mentor.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Is the issue resolved @sam

yes, thanks a lot and my sincere apologies as I thought I have marked it as done.
